# Cannot compile a boost/graph example with C++Builder

Tags: boost, c++builder, boost-graph

I am working with C++Builder 10.3.3 and have installed boost 1.39 for Win32. I tried to compile a simple example from [Quick Tour of Boost Graph Library]
(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/graph/doc/quick_tour.html):

```
#include <iostream>                  // for std::cout
#include <utility>                   // for std::pair
#include <algorithm>                 // for std::for_each
#define BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boyer_myrvold_planar_test.hpp>

  using namespace boost;

  int main(int,char*[])
  {
    // create a typedef for the Graph type
    //typedef adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, bidirectionalS> Graph;
    typedef adjacency_list< vecS, vecS, undirectedS,
        property< vertex_index_t, int > >
        Graph;

    // Make convenient labels for the vertices
    enum { A, B, C, D, E, N };
    const int num_vertices = N;
    const char* name = "ABCDE";

    // writing out the edges in the graph
    typedef std::pair<int, int> Edge;
    Edge edge_array[] =
    { Edge(A,B), Edge(A,D), Edge(C,A), Edge(D,C),
      Edge(C,E), Edge(B,D), Edge(D,E) };
    const int num_edges = sizeof(edge_array)/sizeof(edge_array[0]);

    // declare a graph object
    Graph g(num_vertices);

    // add the edges to the graph object
    for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; ++i)
      add_edge(edge_array[i].first, edge_array[i].second, g);

    bool is_planar = boyer_myrvold_planarity_test(g);

    if (is_planar)
        std::cout << "Graph is planar!" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Graph is not planar." << std::endl;


    return 0;
  }
```

and get many errors of type:

[bcc32c Error] add_const.hpp(33): unknown type name 'add_const_rebind'.

Any idea how to solve this? I'm new with boost and BGL...

Comment: You know these are all decades old, right? 1.39 was released in 2009. Just upgrade. Since C++Builder 10.3.3 is from 2019 it cannot possibly have been one of the supported platforms

Comment: Why not? 10.3.3 was released Nov 2019 and boost 1.39 ten years earlier. Embarcadero did not updated the library for the bcc32 compiler but for bcc32c (Clang) and bcc64 (boost 1.70) [see](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Boost). But I used the wrong compiler (bcc32c instead of bcc32). But with bcc32 I get other errors: [bcc32 Error] multi_index_container_fwd.hpp(17): E2209 Unable to open include file 'boost/multi_index/identity.hpp'...seems /multi_index is missing

Comment: I don't know what you're arguing. That it still happens to work doesn't (remotely) mean it is supported. Or wise. And if you're missing random headers... your install is likely corrupt. 1.39 very much had that header https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/blob/boost-1.39.0/include/boost/multi_index/identity.hpp So either your include paths are wrong in highly original ways ('cause how would it find the other headers?) or your installation is borked.

Comment: I could update C++Builder to 10.4.2 (newest version) and try it again. Or I try to use [LEMON](http://lemon.cs.elte.hu/trac/lemon). It seems to be easier to use than BGL [(comparison)](https://blog.sommer-forst.de/2016/10/28/solving-the-shortest-path-problem-4-comparison-of-lemon-and-bgl/).

Comment: Thanks for your help: I will check the include paths. But I think EMBARCADERO changed a lot in the boost library that it works in C++Builder.

Comment: @Editor: I included the code but it was already there clicking the link "Quick Tour of Boost Graph Library]" and scroll a little bit down. Is the editor a robot?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "editor"; It looks to me you were the only one editing the question. There was a close vote though. You can which people voted to close and for what reason

Comment: I meant the people closing the question. I read now in the help about closing questions and understand the procedure now.

Comment: Did you delete your answer on purpose? It looks like you edited it even after it was deleted?